# Why is the Typescript file in my Angular Component not being generated with a Constructor and an Oninit() life-cycle?

Tags: angular, typescript

Normaly when we do ng generate component new-component , we get a component generated and in the Typescript file we automatically have an OnInit() lifecycle and a constrcutor. I dont know if it  something with the newer version of Angular as i just downloaded it, but it is really stressing me having to implment onInit and adding a constructor in every component.

eg

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent {

}
```

```
import { Component, onInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent impelements onInit {
   constructor()  {}
}
```

Comment: What version of @angular/cli are you using? [Edit] your question to include the answer. You can use `ng version` to find out the information.

Comment: Angular CLI: 15.0.4